# Pandas plot legend=False not working

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend

So, I am ploting two dataframes on same axis:

```
dataframe1.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', linestyle='None')
dataframe1fit.plot(ax=ax1, legend=False)
```

Gives legened only for first dataframe, but is not showing any markers in legend (legend contians only text), so, if I put:

```
ax1.legend(numpoints=1)
```

Markers are added to the legend, but legend entries for dataframe1fit plot are visible too (legend=False has no effect). So, how can I set legend parameters on ax1 not affecting visibility of legend for other dataframes plotted?

Answer (score 0):

dataframe1fit.plot(ax=ax1, legend=None)

Comment: So, this did not solve the problem. My fix for now is to set  `legend=False` for both plots and then set legend by `ax1.legend(...)`, however this solution requires to set legend labels via `labels=`.